# Scrollbar on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Hi guys i have looked all around to find how to do this even in google docs spend hours on it, not sure if i google search awfully or something.
Simple question i have this Column Chart which will display a random number of bars based on data on my DB but i want if its more than 5 or bigger than a size for example to give me a scroll bar
Basically what i want is for the font size and the column width in the chart to stay the same size regardless of how many of them i have but for all of them to appear with a scrollbar
The chart code i have and what i tried bellow:

```
let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));

    const options = {
        title: "Issues per Company for category",
        width: "1000",
        height: "500",
        hAxis: {
            title: "Company Name"
           },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Issue Count"
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

and i have tried to force it to show only 5 in hopes it would show the scroll bar on its own like this

```
 let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));

    const options = {
        title: "Issues per Company for category",
        width: "1000",
        height: "500",
        hAxis: {
            title: "Company Name",
            viewWindowMode: "explicit",
            viewWindow: {
                max:5
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Issue Count"
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

But this didnt work any ideas? Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line has the style that has to be added to the CSS (Cascading Style Sheet) file or the inline query of the page:

```
#detailedCharts {
   overflow-x: scroll;    
}
```

In the above question, the code shows that the chart is bind to an element with Id "detailedCharts", so in the above style the "#detailedCharts" is used to apply style to that element.

```
let chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("detailedCharts"));
```

Comment: This didn't work as i wanted it mabye i explained myself wrong i wanted if for example i had 12 rows to show only 5 and the rest to be visible with a scroll bar

Comment: Yes perfect Thank you very much will accept the answer in 2 mins when i am allowed to

Comment: Hi, i also wanted to show scroll bar when the number of bars increases... when i tried above code, the columns which are hidden is not in DOM itself.  when i inspect element, i dont see the remaining column bars.  can you help me here? how does the columns outside the viewWindow still show up?  can you share your example in jsfiddle? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are saying. From that: set a width: 100% and max-width: XXXpx; When I increase the number of bar I still have the scrollbar...